# Triangle inequality in sum of summations

Tags: inequality, summation, triangle-inequality

I have $$a_i^t-a_i^*=\sum_{b\in B}b+\sum_{c\in C}c,\\B\ne C,\\B, C \subset R$$
Can I say that $$|a_i^t-a_i^*|\le\sum_{b\in B}|b|+\sum_{c\in C}|c|?$$

Comment: yes, this is a consequence of the triangle inequality

Comment: @angryavian Ok thanks. Can you answer the question so I can mark as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triangle inequality implies $\left|\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right| \le \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|$ for any real numbers $x_1, \ldots, x_n$. Your inequality follows from a direct application of this fact.